# jQuery ajax working on local file but not working from a remote url?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am currently trying to get data from a remote url using jQuery ajax calls.

I am just using a basic jquery function to do this. When using a local file the functions works correctly but it does not get a remote file.

I'm using the local files using Mamp on my local pc.

```
$.ajax({
url: "URL",
success: function(data) {
    $('#notification').html(data);
}
});
```

Any ideas why this may not be work would be a great help?

Thanks,
Kane

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You might need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 1):

when you say 'remote file' do you mean like from another domain? coz browsers typically don't allow that.

See this [JQuery external Ajax call not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101731/jquery-external-ajax-call-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain ajax request is not allowed typically. You can take a look to these answers:

[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

[problem with cross-domain ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304530/problem-with-cross-domain-ajax-calls)